# Liquibase: changeset auto generate ID

Tags: liquibase

How to auto generate ID of changeset with liquibase?

I don't want to set the ID of every changeset manually, is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: No, there isn't (at least nothing built-in)

Comment: I doubt that will (can) work. Here's why: Liquibase can create/update/etc your schema. For that it executes what you put into its changeset file. It then stores the changes it executed in its own table to know what it has done already. If it generated a random ID each time you restart the application, it would never be able to figure out what changes have already been run and which haven't. The only alternative (I could think of) is to dig into liquibase src and have the ID generated of a hash of the changeset (even that may cause collisions).If I am misunderstanding your question, let me know

Comment: Question - how are you currently creating your changesets?

Comment: thanks a lot for your replies. @Stevedonie i create all changesets in one changelog.

Comment: No, I mean what are the exact steps you use to create a changeset? Do you use a liquibase command? Do you use notepad? Generally, when reporting any kind of problem, it is super helpful to include three things - 1 - these are the steps that I took, 2- this is what actually happened, 3 - this is what I expected to happen. You did not include any of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think that generated ids are a good idea. The reason is that liquibase uses the changeSet id to calculate the checksum (in addition to the author and fileName). So if you ever insert a changeSet between others the checksums of all subsequent changeSets will change and you will get tons of warnings/errors.

Anyway i can think of those solutions if you still want to generate Ids:

1. create your own [ChangeLogParser](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/ChangeLogParser)

If you parse the ChangeLog on your own you are free to generate the ids as you want.
The downside is that you will have to provide a custom Xml Schema for the changeLog. The schema from Liquibase has a constraint on changeSet ids (required). With a new schema you'll probably have to do a significant amount of tweaking on the parser.
Alternatively you may choose another changeLog Format (YAML, JSON, Groovy). Their parsers may be easier to customize as they do not need that schema definition.

2. Do some preprocessing

You may write a simple xslt (Xml transformation) that generates a changeLog with changeSet ids, from a file that has none.

3. use timestamps as Ids

This would be my advice. It does not solve the question the way you asked, but it is simple, consistent, provides additional information and is a good practice for other database migration tools as well http://www.jeremyjarrell.com/using-flyway-db-with-distributed-version-control/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python script to generate unique IDs into Liquibase changelogs.

**Be careful!**

*DO generate IDs*

- when the changelog is in development or ready for release
- or when you control the checksums of the target database

*DON'T generate IDs*
 - when the changelog(s) are deployed already

```
"""
###############################################################################
Purpose: Generate unique subsequent IDs into Liquibase changelogs
###############################################################################

Args:
    param1:     Full Windows path changelog directory (optional) 
                OR
                --inplace: directly process changelogs (optional) 

    By default, XML files in the current directory are processed.

Returns:
    In case of success, the output path is returned to stdout. 
    Otherwise, we crash and drag the system into mordor.

    If you feel like wasting time you can: 
        a) port path handling to *nix 
        b) handle any obscure exceptions 
        c) add Unicode support (for better entertainment)

Dependencies:
    Besides Python 3, in order to preserve XML comments, I had to use lxml 
    instead of the stock ElementTree parser. 
    Install lxml:

    $ pip install lxml

    Proxy clusterfuck? Don't panic! Simply download a .whl package from: 
    https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files and install with pip.

Bugs:
    Changesets having id="0" are ignored. Usually, these do not occur.    

Author:
    Tobias Bräutigam 

Versions:
    0.0.1 - re based, deprecated
    0.0.2 - parse XML with lxml, CURRENT 
"""

import datetime
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

try:    
    import lxml.etree as ET
except ImportError as error:
    print (''' 
    Error: module lxml is missing.
    Please install it:

    pip install lxml
    ''')
    exit()

# Process arguments
prefix = '' # hold separator, if needed 
outdir = 'out'

try: sys.argv[1]
except: pass
else:
    if sys.argv[1] == '--inplace':
        outdir = ''
    else:                
        prefix = outdir + '//'
        # accept Windows path syntax
        inpath = PureWindowsPath(sys.argv[1]) 
        # convert path format
        inpath = Path(inpath) 
        os.chdir(inpath) 
        try: os.mkdir(outdir)
        except: pass
        filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(outdir) ]
        for f in filelist: os.remove(os.path.join(outdir, f))

# Parse XML, generate IDs, write file 
def parseX(filename,prefix):    
    cnt = 0    
    print (filename)
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    for node in tree.getiterator():
        if int(node.attrib.get('id', 0)):                        
            now = datetime.datetime.now()            
            node.attrib['id'] = str(int(now.strftime("%H%M%S%f"))+cnt*37)
            cnt = cnt + 1 
    root = tree.getroot()
    # NS URL element name is '' for Etree, lxml requires at least one character
    ET.register_namespace('x', u'http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog') 
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)        
    tree.write(prefix + filename, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
    print(str(cnt) +' ID(s) generated.')

# Process files
print('\n')
items = 0
for infile in os.listdir('.'):
    if (infile.lower().endswith('.xml')) == True:      
        parseX(infile,prefix)
        items=items+1

# Message
print('\n' + str(items) + ' file(s) processed.\n\n')
if items > 0:
    print('Output was written to: \n\n')    
    print(str(os.getcwd()) + '\\' + outdir + '\n')
```